# Salvar quantidade de ocorrências de um arquivo txt em outro arquivo txt em python

Tags: python

Esse parte do código conta a quantidade de vezes que as palavras repetem no texto:

```
with open('/Users/DIGITAL/Desktop/Python/teste.txt') as f:
    ocorrencias = Counter(f.read().split())
```

Essa parte é usada pra ordenar em ordem crescente:

```
with open('/Users/DIGITAL/Desktop/Python/teste.txt') as f:

    palavras = Counter( f.read().split())
print ("Ordem por número de ocorrências:",ordenar(palavras, reverse=False))
```

Eu preciso saber um jeito de salvar o resultado disso `{palavras = Counter( f.read().split())}` num novo arquivo txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dicionários não possuem ordenção em `Python`! O segredo é converter o dicionário para uma lista de tuplas para então ordena-la:

```
from collections import Counter

# Abre arquivo de Entrada para leitura
with open('texto.txt', 'r') as f:

    # Calcula Quantidade de cada Palavra no Arquivo
    # e retorna um dicionario
    dic = Counter( f.read().split() )

# Converte Items do Dicionario Para Lista de Tuplas
lst = list(dic.items());

# Ordena Lista de Tuplas
lst.sort( key=lambda tup: tup[1])

# Abre arquivo de Saida para gravacao
with open('saida.txt','w') as f:

    # Para cada tupla na lista
    for tup in lst:

        # Grava linha no arquivo de Saida
        f.write( tup[0] + ":" + str(tup[1]) + "\n" )
```

**texto.txt**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu
lectus lobortis condimentum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor
massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla at risus. Quisque purus magna, auctor et, sagittis
ac, posuere eu, lectus. Nam mattis, felis ut adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum.
```

**saida.txt**

```
habitant:1
Nulla:1
at:1
felis:1
morbi:1
Nam:1
lectus.:1
senectus:1
mattis,:1
posuere:1
purus:1
egestas.:1
tristique:1
Pellentesque:1
eu,:1
Quisque:1
condimentum.Lorem:1
et,:1
risus.:1
fames:1
massa.:1
nonummy:1
ac,:1
netus:1
adipiscing.:1
ut:1
ac:1
turpis:1
magna,:1
sagittis:1
Aliquam:1
malesuada:1
condimentum.:2
Lorem:2
auctor:2
et:2
amet,:3
ipsum:3
sit:3
lectus:3
ligula:3
consectetur:3
adipiscing:3
eget:3
dolor:3
eu:3
Etiam:3
lobortis:3
elit.:3
```